# update multiple values in a single Observable in angular 5

Tags: angular

The scenario seems simple but i could not figure it out. I have the following code to give me a decrementing number per second:

```
counter: number;
countDown: number;

ngOnInit(){

this.counter = this._cookies.get('remainingTime');

if(this.counter > 0){
  this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .take(this.counter)
    .map(() => --this.counter );

  this._cookies.set('remainingTime', () => Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .take(this.counter)
    .map(() => --this.counter ));
}
}
```

I can get `countDown` decremented but could not do it for the cookie `remainingTime`. What should i do? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to update the cookie and the value countDown every second, then do it in a function like this:

```
timer: any;
timerSubscription: any;
ngOnInit(){

  this.counter = this._cookies.get('remainingTime');
  this.countdDown = counter;

  if(this.counter > 0){
    this.timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
    this.timerSubscription = timer.subscribe(t => this.timerFunction());
  }
}

timerFunction() {
   this.countDown = this.countDown - 1;
   this._cookies.set('remainingTime', this.countDown);
   if (this.countDown === 0) {
      this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.timer = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. now I do not have `countDown` either. What is that `t` doing there?

Comment: In console I get `countDown` and the cookie as `NaN`

Comment: It should work. Make sure that the value for 'remainingTime' is a number when getting it from the cookie, then make it be a number

Comment: I did: `this.counter = Number(this._cookies.get('remainingTime'));` But still the same

Comment: right after you do that, do if (isNaN(this.counter)) and if that is true then set it to zero

Comment: hmmmm, interesting. What happens if you change your initial delay in your timer from zero to something like 25 milliseconds?

Comment: can you use session storage instead of cookies? window.sessionStorage.setItem('remainingTime', 60); window.sessionStorage.getItem('remainingTime');

Comment: Now I get `countDown` properly. In the question I used `.map()` to return the counter value to show it on the page, but how can I do that using your approach.

Comment: within timerFunction it is decrementing the timer directly every second because that timerFunction is executed every second, so just do {{ countDown }} in your html where you need to display it. You don't need to use .map()